# How to pass a PowerShell variable to maven -Dtest to individually run multiple tests

Tags: powershell, maven

I need to use PowerShell to run `mvn test` on all test cases individually. I tried to create a `Foreach` loop where I recursively pass every test case through `mvn test -Dtest` but I keep receiving errors of different kinds, but in every case, the individual tests don't run for some reason.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\me\project\src\test" -Filter *.java -Recurse -Name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | ForEach-Object {
        $file = ($_ -split '\\')[-1]
        $name = $file.substring(0,$file.length-5)
        mvn test -Dtest=$name
        }
```

However, when I don't pass a variable to `mvn test -Dtest` and give it an actual test class name (for example: `mvn test -Dtest=AddTest`), the test runs normally. The problems seems to be with `$name` getting passed to `-Dtest` because I opened this script in VS Code and it said that the `$name` variable is never used after being declared even though I use it in the very next line with `mvn test -Dtest=$name`.

Here is the main error I've been receiving

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.0:test (default-test) on project: No tests were executed!
```

Comment: "but I keep receiving errors of different kinds" - it would be mighty helpful if you included one or more examples of errors you've received :) That being said, `mvn test "-Dtest=$name"` might solve the problem

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thank you so much!

Comment: Why do you need to get all files separately instead of using Maven (maven-surefire-plugin) itself? Why do you need that? Let Maven do the work it's easier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing an **unfortunate bug in PowerShell's parameter binder**, still present as of PowerShell 7.2.

To work around it, **pass your argument as an [expandable string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375)**, as [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) suggests in a comment:

```sh
mvn test "-Dtest=$name"
```

In short, **the bug is**:

- If an argument is `-`-prefixed, embedded variable references such as `$name` are unexpectedly *not* expanded,  unless there happens to be a preceding `:` character.
- Presumably, PowerShell thinks that everything following the `-`, even past a `=`, is a *parameter name*, and is therefore used *verbatim* (in PowerShell, it is `:` that separates a parameter name from its value *if* passed as a single token, which is not common).
- See [GitHub issue #14587](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14587).

Comment: omg thank you so much, you're a lifesaver

Comment: My pleasure, @kyotosakobe. I just noticed that Mathias had essentially provided the solution in a comment too, but I hope the explanation is also useful.

Comment: oh wow i didn't even notice, i haven't posted much on stack overflow so i completely forgot to check the comments properly. thank you lol